# Is there a connection between State variable and Widget variable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have following problem:

I have a Stafeful Widget where I pass the parameter `[Text('Test1'), Text('Test2')]`:

```
class FirstWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Text> names;
  const FirstWidget(this.names);

  @override
  _FirstWidgetState createState() => _FirstWidgetState();
}

class _FirstWidgetState extends State<FirstWidget> {
  late List<Text> stateNames;

  @override
  void initState() {
    stateNames = widget.names;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ElevatedButton(
        child: Text('Click Me'),
        onPressed: () {
          stateNames.add(Text('This is the new Test3'));
          print('STATE: $stateNames');
          print('WIDGET: ${widget.names}');
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I press the Button, a new Text Widget gets added to the List and I get following print in the console:

```
STATE: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2"), Text("This is the new Test3")]
WIDGET: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2"), Text("This is the new Test3")]
```

I don't understand that, because I only added the Text to the `stateNames` variable. Where is the connection between `widget.names` and `stateNames`??
I would expect this output:

```
STATE: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2"), Text("This is the new Test3")]
WIDGET: [Text("Test1"), Text("Test2")]
```

How can I prevent this behaviour, that also the widget variable gets changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### **You are giving reference to the `stateNames`.**

##### By changing the contents of the stateNames the Same will happen with `widget.names`.

- To prevent this from happening you have to assign a copy of `widget.name` to the `stateNames` in `initState`.
- You can simply do that by spread operator like this

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    stateNames = [...widget.names];
    super.initState();
  }
```

- You can do this:

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    stateNames = widget.names.toList();
    super.initState();
  }
```

- Or you can do this

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    stateNames = List.from(widget.names);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works exactly the way I want it. I was not aware that only after applying .toList() to a list creates an actual copy and not only a reference.

Comment: Yes, I recommend using `List.from(widget.names);` this approach as it is more efficient. This will not affect performance too much but it is efficient.